# How to change the struts-config.xml dynamically?

Tags: java, struts

Recently I am trying Java with Struts 1.
While I was playing with the  tag in my struts-config.xml,
I was wondering whether I can set the attribute, mainly **path** in struts-config.xml dynamically?
Like using the value of a variable in the Action.java to config the xml file to have a dynamic forwarding path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the last comment in [this post on JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/49439/Struts/Dynamic-action-forward), I had to do this in the past and I believe that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to change the struts-config dynamically because struts-config.xml file was load the time of the deployment so if it is load single time then without restart server not possible to load.